# All combinations from data frame in R

Tags: r, combinations

I'm trying to find all combinations (not permutations, order doesn't matter) from a list with various restrictions on the structure of each combination. I know combn() will do the trick for a simple list and I've tried using sample(), but my need is more complex.

I have a data frame that has three columns, name, type, cost. I want to find all possible combinations of names in sets of 7 (so 7 names) where one is of type 1, three are of type 2 and the rest are of type 3 and the total cost is less than a set variable.

I'm at a total loss for how to do this and I'm not even certain R is the right language to do this in. Should I try a for loop with some nested if statements?

```
> dput(head(sample))
structure(list(Name = structure(c(6L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Amber", 
"Cyndi", "E", "Eric", "Hannah", "Jason", "Jesse", "Jim ", "Lisa", 
"Lucy", "Matt", "Ryan", "Tat"), class = "factor"), Type = c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), Cost = c(6000L, 6200L, 9000L, 2000L, 8000L, 
4500L)), .Names = c("Name", "Type", "Cost"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8.1    ggplot2_1.0.0 dplyr_0.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1   colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.1.2     MASS_7.3-33     
 [7] munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.1.1   proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2      reshape2_1.4     scales_0.2.4    
[13] stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1
```

Example data:

```
Name    Type    Cost
Jason   2   6000
Jim     3   6200
Eric    3   9000
Lisa    1   2000
Cyndi   3   8000
Hannah  3   4500
E       2   7200
Matt    1   3200
Jesse   3   1200
Tat     3   3200
Ryan    1   5600
Amber   2   5222
Lucy    2   1000
```

One possible combination if total cost is set to 60k:

Lisa, Jason, Amber, Lucy, Tat, Jesse, Hannah

That's one possible combination, as Lisa is type 1, Jason, Amber and Lucy are type 2 and the remaining three are type 3 and the total cost of all 7 is below 60k. Another possible combination would be:

Ryan, Jason, Amber, Lucy, Tat, Jesse, Hannah

Ryan has replaced Lisa as the type 1 from the first combination. The cost is still below 60k.

I'm trying to get all possible combinations where the conditions above are true.

Comment: Seem a simple application for `expand.grid` with appropriate inputs. It's your responsibility to provide an example dataset.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll edit this question to include more details to make it reproducible.

Comment: Have you tried `expand.grid(sample)` or not?

Comment: expand.grid(sample) isn't quite right. Maybe with the correct inputs it would work, but the type and cost are tied to the name. Expand.grid() doesn't appear to treat these three columns as linked and instead is giving all possible combinations of the three columns such that one combination might be Sue, type 1, 5200 and a second combination might be Sue, Type 2, 6000.

Comment: So all you need is aggregation? Something like `aggregate(Cost ~ Name+Type, sample,sum)`? (Didn't test this cause not infront of a computer)

Comment: Nope. I need all combinations of 7 names where 1 person is type three, three people are type 2 and three people are type 3 with the total cost being less than a set variable.

Comment: Please provide your desired output, otherwise it is literally impossible to understand what are you looking for

Comment: Added some example outputs, hopefully that helps clarify. This is a conditional combinations question. I don't know if that is coming through in my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution using loops (maybe not the most efficient):

```
# Example data
Name <- c('Jason', 'Jim','Eric', 'Lisa', 'Cyndi', 'Hanna','Jon','Matt',
          'Jerry','Emily','Mary','Cynthia')
Type <- c(2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2)
Cost <- c(9200, 8200, 9000, 8700, 9100, 8900, 9800, 7800, 9600, 
          9300, 8100, 7800)

df <- data.frame(Name, Type,Cost)
v1 <- subset(df, Type==1)
v2 <- subset(df, Type==2)
v3 <- subset(df, Type==3)

# Get all combinations of desired size of subsets
m1 <- v1$Name
m2 <- combn(v2$Name, 3)
m3 <- combn(v3$Name, 3)

n1 <- length(m1)
n2 <- ncol(m2)
n3 <- ncol(m3)

# put combinations of subsets together
all.combs <- as.list(rep(NA, n1*n2*n3))
idx <- 1
for (i in 1:n1) {
  for (j in 1:n2) {
    for (k in 1:n3) {
      all.combs[[idx]] <- c(as.character(m1[i]),
                            as.character(m2[,j]),
                            as.character(m3[,k]))
      idx <- idx + 1
    }
  }
}

# Check for total cost < 60K
cond <- rep(NA, length(all.combs))
for (i in 1:length(all.combs)) {
   sum <- 0
   for (j in 1:7) {
      sum <- sum + df$Cost[df$Name==all.combs[[i]][j]]
   }
   cond[i] <- sum < 60000
}
res <- all.combs[cond]
res
```

Comment: This is very close and I'm pretty sure I can repurpose this for a final answer. But where you are currently giving three people I would like seven with a certain 'set structure' - namely one person of type 1, three people of type 2 and three people of type 3. Additionally, the cost restriction is for the whole set, not for each individual. For example, if I had a group of twenty men and women with unique salaries, I might ask for a set of seven with four women and three men with a total cost of the set being less than 60k.

Comment: Yes, sorry @MatthewHartwig I just edited my response. This should do the trick.